# python transpose a dataframe and group and append new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to arrange a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
{'Sample': {0: 'Mark', 1: 'Mark', 2: 'Mark', 3: 'Mark', 4: 'Mark', 5: 'John', 6: 'John', 7: 'John', 8: 'John', 9: 'John', 10: 'Lisa', 11: 'Lisa', 12: 'Lisa', 13: 'Lisa', 14: 'Lisa'}, 'CO': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 10, 6: 11, 7: 11, 8: 14, 9: 11, 10: 23, 11: 25, 12: 26, 13: 23, 14: 45}, 'Argon': {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 9, 3: 5, 4: 7, 5: 45, 6: 65, 7: 45, 8: 67, 9: 43, 10: 34, 11: 78, 12: 79, 13: 87, 14: 67}, 'Carbon': {0: 35, 1: 43, 2: 78, 3: 54, 4: 34, 5: 56, 6: 58, 7: 50, 8: 53, 9: 55, 10: 87, 11: 77, 12: 88, 13: 89, 14: 85}}
```

| Sample | CO | Argon | Carbon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | 3 | 7 | 35 |
| Mark | 3 | 8 | 43 |
| Mark | 2 | 9 | 78 |
| Mark | 4 | 5 | 54 |
| Mark | 5 | 7 | 34 |
| John | 10 | 45 | 56 |
| John | 11 | 65 | 58 |
| John | 11 | 45 | 50 |
| John | 14 | 67 | 53 |
| John | 11 | 43 | 55 |
| Lisa | 23 | 34 | 87 |
| Lisa | 25 | 78 | 77 |
| Lisa | 26 | 79 | 88 |
| Lisa | 23 | 87 | 89 |
| Lisa | 45 | 67 | 85 |

To this:

```
{'Chemical': {0: 'Argon', 1: 'Argon', 2: 'Argon', 3: 'Argon', 4: 'Argon', 5: 'Carbon', 6: 'Carbon', 7: 'Carbon', 8: 'Carbon', 9: 'Carbon', 10: 'CO', 11: 'CO', 12: 'CO', 13: 'CO', 14: 'CO'}, 'Mark': {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 9, 3: 5, 4: 7, 5: 35, 6: 43, 7: 78, 8: 54, 9: 34, 10: 3, 11: 3, 12: 2, 13: 4, 14: 5}, 'John': {0: 45, 1: 65, 2: 45, 3: 67, 4: 43, 5: 56, 6: 58, 7: 50, 8: 53, 9: 55, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 11, 13: 14, 14: 11}, 'Lisa': {0: 34, 1: 78, 2: 79, 3: 87, 4: 67, 5: 87, 6: 77, 7: 88, 8: 89, 9: 85, 10: 23, 11: 25, 12: 26, 13: 23, 14: 45}}
```

| Chemical | Mark | John | Lisa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Argon | 7 | 45 | 34 |
| Argon | 8 | 65 | 78 |
| Argon | 9 | 45 | 79 |
| Argon | 5 | 67 | 87 |
| Argon | 7 | 43 | 67 |
| Carbon | 35 | 56 | 87 |
| Carbon | 43 | 58 | 77 |
| Carbon | 78 | 50 | 88 |
| Carbon | 54 | 53 | 89 |
| Carbon | 34 | 55 | 85 |
| CO | 3 | 10 | 23 |
| CO | 3 | 11 | 25 |
| CO | 2 | 11 | 26 |
| CO | 4 | 14 | 23 |
| CO | 5 | 11 | 45 |

The data is body measurements of three people, and each chemical was measured 5 times per person

It looks like a simple case of transposing, but not surprisingly, it does exactly what it says on the tin! I've also tried melting the dataframe and groupby, but I'm really not getting anywhere with it. Any help would be most welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't use image, update your post with plain text data. Copy/Paste the content of your file or post the output of `print(df.to_dict())`

Comment: Thank you Corralien, noted for future posts too!

Comment: If you install `tabulate` package you can use `print(df.to_markdown(index=False))` to get the above output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `melt` with `pivot_table` in one-liner version:

```
>>> df.melt('Sample', var_name='Chemical') \
      .assign(Idx=lambda x: x.groupby('Sample').cumcount()) \
      .pivot_table('value', ['Idx', 'Chemical'], 'Sample') \
      .droplevel(0).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()

   Chemical  John  Lisa  Mark
0        CO    10    23     3
1        CO    11    25     3
2        CO    11    26     2
3        CO    14    23     4
4        CO    11    45     5
5     Argon    45    34     7
6     Argon    65    78     8
7     Argon    45    79     9
8     Argon    67    87     5
9     Argon    43    67     7
10   Carbon    56    87    35
11   Carbon    58    77    43
12   Carbon    50    88    78
13   Carbon    53    89    54
14   Carbon    55    85    34
```

You can execute all steps independently to see the transformation:

```
>>> out = df.melt('Sample', var_name='Chemical')
>>> out = out.assign(Idx=lambda x: x.groupby('Sample').cumcount())
>>> out = out.pivot_table('value', ['Idx', 'Chemical'], 'Sample')
>>> out = out.droplevel(0).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
dfm = df.melt('Sample', var_name='Chemical')
dfm.set_index([dfm.groupby('Sample').cumcount(), 'Chemical', 'Sample']).unstack()['value']
```

Output:

```
Sample       John  Lisa  Mark
   Chemical                  
0  CO          10    23     3
1  CO          11    25     3
2  CO          11    26     2
3  CO          14    23     4
4  CO          11    45     5
5  Argon       45    34     7
6  Argon       65    78     8
7  Argon       45    79     9
8  Argon       67    87     5
9  Argon       43    67     7
10 Carbon      56    87    35
11 Carbon      58    77    43
12 Carbon      50    88    78
13 Carbon      53    89    54
14 Carbon      55    85    34
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = a.set_index("Sample")
pd.concat([a.loc[nm].unstack().rename(nm).droplevel("Sample")
           for nm in a.index.unique()], axis=1)
#         Mark  John  Lisa
# CO         3    10    23
# CO         3    11    25
# CO         2    11    26
# CO         4    14    23
# CO         5    11    45
# Argon      7    45    34
# Argon      8    65    78
# Argon      9    45    79
# Argon      5    67    87
# Argon      7    43    67
# Carbon    35    56    87
# Carbon    43    58    77
# Carbon    78    50    88
# Carbon    54    53    89
# Carbon    34    55    85
```